# Parent scope after changing view template using ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a controller who changes its view using 2 ng-include( tried both file and script). One for view and other for edit screen.

```
<div class="content-area">
<div class='row'>
    <div class="cs-info">
        <fp-info-bar config="headerConfig"></fp-info-bar>

        <ng-include src="currentTemplate"></ng-include>

    </div>
</div>
```

View template do not have inputs. The edit template have a form, 4 ng-form which them self contain inputs and custom directives.

```
<ng-form name='premisesAddressForm' attempt>
            <div has-permission='CustomerDetailEditOverrideAddressValidation'>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isPremisesAutoCorrectDisabled"><span>Turn off Auto Correct</span>
            </div>
            <fp-address-edit
                    states="states"
                    ng-model='customer.PremisesAddress'
                    on-change="validateAddress(customer.PremisesAddress, premisesAddressForm, isPremisesAutoCorrectDisabled)">
            </fp-address-edit>
        </ng-form>
```

Data gets successfully populated and other things works fine too with in directive in edit mode.

**Problem:** When i try to save data on parent controller and check scope, i do not find any form(premisesAddressForm) or other input fields on edit template. i.e. this `$scope.premisesAddressForm` do not exist. Just to make clear, the save button is on same template and is bind to function on parent controller, no problems with that. I tried creating objects with in parent controller like this but no use.

```
$scope.forms = {};
<ng-form name='froms.premisesAddressForm' attempt>
```

I know ng-include create its own scope (inherit form parent) but i am not trying to get parent objects on child so no issues there. I also read some where that after ng-include changes, Angular compiles and updates the scope. To me there lies the problem. How i supposed to make it work? If my approach is wrong all together, please feel free to point out. My objective is to use same controller for different views, with different inputs or none. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that ngInclude creates a new child scope. The problem is that the parent scope will not have access to child scoped properties. What you could do is the same thing you tried, but instead of passing the form back to the parent controller, you should pass the values back.

In your parent controller:

```
$scope.myObj = {
  customer: {}
};
```

In your template:

```
<ng-form name='premisesAddressForm' attempt>
            <div has-permission='CustomerDetailEditOverrideAddressValidation'>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myObj.isPremisesAutoCorrectDisabled"><span>Turn off Auto Correct</span>
            </div>
            <fp-address-edit
                    states="states"
                    ng-model='myObj.customer.PremisesAddress'
                    on-change="validateAddress(myObj.customer.PremisesAddress, premisesAddressForm, myObj.isPremisesAutoCorrectDisabled)">
            </fp-address-edit>
        </ng-form>
```

If you need for the controllers to communicate during saving (e.g. kick off validation), you could use events.

Comment: Hey Vadim, thanks for the reply. Its been just a week i started Angular so sorry if i do not understand you correctly. The HTML above is part of template and ng-model, states are populating it. This is working fine. Problem is i can not get the ng-form (premisesAddressForm) in my parent controller. When i write $scope.premisesAddressForm, its not defined. Can you explain a bit further?

Comment: Suppose i want to check $dirty before submitting, how would i check this if i cannot access it?

Comment: @ali There are several ways you can do it and it all depends on what you're trying to do. If you're handling this on an action like a save, I would suggest using events to handle this kind of flow. I.e. the parent scope notifies the children that something is happening.

Comment: So are you suggesting to perform actual save in child template controller? At the moment i do not have controller for  different templates. Should i make one? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @ali, no not the save in the child template controller, but the child controller could respond to an event to save the object and could return to the parent scope some information. Familiarize yourself with how scopes handle eventing https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope